# Extract Data from Google search

Tags: javascript, html, google-search

I am trying to extract facts from Google's new fun facts feature. If you search fun facts in google you get a question and an answer. I want to store a bunch of these facts somewhere to be used later.

I have tried using javascript to extract the div the fun fact is in. However, Google's div's are dynamic and change every time you search. If I try to use an API or just try and execute the search using https://www.google.com/search?q=fun+facts I get the regular search results but not Google's special fun fact results.

Is there a way I can do this mimic the search to return the special results and then store the data in a file or somewhere?

EDIT:
Google seems to block iframes

```
<html>
<div> 
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/search?q=fun+facts"></iframe>
</div>
</html>
```

Now on to using pure javascript and window.open

```
<script>
   var win = window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=fun+facts");
   //wait for window to load before trying to access it
</script>
```

EDIT 2:
I can't seem to get around the cross domain issue. Is there a way to open a window and extract the html from it that's not on the same domain? I can't seem to find a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: you could use custom google search

Comment: I could. However, Google's facts don't appear when I do a custom search which is the whole reason I'm trying to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with selectors.

This grabs the question:

```
$('[data-md=137] > div > div:nth-child(1)')
```

This one grabs the answer:

```
$('[data-md=137] > div > div:nth-child(2) > :nth-child(2)')
```

And this one grabs the source:

```
('[data-md=137] > div > div:nth-child(3) p:last-child')
```

If you want to test those, go to  [https://www.google.com/search?q=fun+facts](https://www.google.com/search?q=fun%20facts) and pull up the console (F12), load jQuery in the console first:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
jQuery.noConflict();
```

...then try the selectors above.

Comment: Great! That works! Now I know how to get the information. Is there anyway I can do it all through code without using the Console, because I would like to just keep searching and extracting the facts. I don't think you can just make a web request from a custom html page

Comment: I'm really glad it works for you :)

With the knowledge I gave you, all you have to do is some... work, haha. Create an iframe/webview, load the google search into it, wait for the search to finish and then extract the links from the iframe/webview into your application page and do what you want with them.

Comment: Ok great, thanks again. I guess I'll have to start trying things out. But at least I'm going in the right direction.